# Is zkBNB a blockchain or just a layer 2 application?

Tags: binance-smart-chain

I found zkBNB to be a scaling solution for Binance Smart Chain (BSC), but didn't find in its docs if it is a blockchain. It is?

Answer (score 1):

zkBNB is a layer 2 blockchain scaling framework for Binance Smart Chain. ZkBNB is built on ZK Rollup architecture. Following are the key modules in the framework as per [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/bnb-chain/zkbnb#Framework). As it produces blocks, translates them to transactions and generates cryptographic proofs and send them to layer 1 BSC chain, we can consider them as a layer 2 blockchain.

- Committer. Committer executes transactions and produce consecutive
  blocks.
- Monitor. Monitor tracks events on BSC, and translates them into
  transactions on ZkBNB.
- Witness. Witness re-executes the transactions within the block and
  generates witness materials.
- Prover. Prover generates cryptographic proof based on the witness
  materials.
- Sender. The sender rollups the compressed l2 blocks to L1, and submit
  proof to verify it.
- Api server. The api server is the access endpoints for most users, it
  provides rich data, including digital assets, blocks, transactions,
  gas fees.
- Recovery. A tool to recover the sparse merkle tree in kv-rocks based on the state world in postgresql.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Gokul! Does it have a consensus protocol to add blocks to the chain? I think that is a must to be considered a blockchain

Comment: As rollup based approaches follow a modular blockchain architecture, execcuction layer, data availability layer, consensus layer, and settlement layer, are separate. Transactions are ordered in the execution layer using the combination of committer, monitor and sender modules. As there is a transaction ordering happening in the L2 using a set of distributed modules, it is possible to consider them as a modular blockchain.

Comment: Great! Thanks Gokul